# Trying to modify ACL on multiple objects and folders on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, amazon-cloudfront

I need to update the ACL settings of over 1600 objects that are in over 160 folders in an S3 bucket.

The files have already been uploaded into s3.

Specifically, I need to do the following:

1. Give the owner (i.e. me) FULL CONTROL
2. disable anonymous/public READs
3. give my CloudFront user READ access (as determined by the canonical ID retrieved for the Origin Access Identity)

The files and folders have a standard naming convention:

- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX.mp4
- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX.webm
- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX.ogv
- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX-pf.jpg
- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX-lg.jpg
- s3://bucket/videos/XXXX/XXXX-sm.jpg

`XXXX` is replaced by a number between `0001` and `9999`

What is the easiest way to do that, because using the console is extremely time consuming.

I have **s3cmd** configured on my server. Can **s3cmd** handle that...and what would the syntax be?

If not **s3cmd**, what other tool would be available...command line preferred.

Comment: Write a bash or other api script to loop through all the files.

Comment: @datasage I am not knowledgable enough to do that. Could you help me?

Answer (score -1):

S3 bucket policies are the answer. Taken care of. Just thought I'd mention this.

Comment: This isn't an answer, should be a comment